# Custom View remove all postInvalidate()

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

As [Writing Custom View for Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA) said:

> Remove any posted Runnable in onDetachedFromWindow

I have a custom view, `CircleCheckBox`. When it's clicked animation will be executed.

[image]

The animation is implemented by `View#postInvalidate()`.

**So is there a way to remove any posted runnable in `onDetachedFromWindow()`**?

### EDIT

Let me tell you how `CircleCheckBox` works.

#### Step 1

In `CircleCheckBox` constructor I set `View#OnClickListener` for it:

```
this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggle();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCheckedChanged(isChecked());
        }
    }
});
```

### Step 2

In method `toggle()` it will invoke:

```
@Override
public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    ....
    if (checked) {
        startCheckedAnimation();
    } else {
        startUnCheckedAnimation();
    }
}
```

### Step 3

Let's say `startCheckedAnimation()`.

```
 private void startCheckedAnimation() {
    // circle animation
    ValueAnimator circleAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
    circleAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    circleAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            mArcPath.reset();
            mArcPath.addArc(mRectF, -159, 360 * (1 - value));
            postInvalidate();
        }
    });
    circleAnimator.setDuration(mDuration / 4);
    circleAnimator.start();
  }
```

I use `postInvalidate()` method to let view invoke `onDraw()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`View#clearAnimation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()) will cancel all animations that have been applied to the `View`.

In your case you are using a `ValueAnimator`, which means that you have to keep a reference to it and when you need to cancel the animation you should perform [`ValueAnimator#cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#cancel()):

```
private ValueAnimator circleAnimator;

...

circleAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
// setup and start `ValueAnimator`
```

Then, when needed to cancel the animation:

```
circleAnimator.cancel();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,however the custom view does not have `Animation mCurrentAnimation`.I will update my question.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to see how you run this animation.

Comment: Thx.Your answer is useful and reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use  [removeCallbacks(Runnable r)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)method.

> void [removeCallbacks (Runnable r)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

Comment: But how can I get `r`?